# Use Joins and Fetch Data with Filter using SAP Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am new in Crystal Report, I've created a Crystal Report successfully by following methods:

- Created Crystal Report As Blank
- get into Database Expert and create Database using OLE DB(ADO)
- in OLE DB(ADO) I simply add tables into the Database and showed it on Crystal Report
- Then I created a Win form on which I used Crystal Report Viewer
- then I use following Code on Crystal Report Viewer Tab to call the Crystal Report

**Code:**

```
            var cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(@"C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\PROJECT INVENTORY SOFTWARE\InventorySoftware\InventorySoftware\Crystal Reports\CrystalReport2.rpt");
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Now what it does, it fetches complete table data, like if I have 500 records then it will load all the 500 records, and that's what I don't want to do.

What I actually need to do is to fetch data of a specific invoice number and I am not able to do this in any way.

I want it to fetch data for only that invoice number which is written on the form at run time, and the query through which I want to fetch data is build using Joins.

I am stuck and doing Google from past 3 hours but not able to do it.

Please dear SO fellows help me out. I will be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure about `c# code`  but why don't you try filtering data using `Record Sort Expert`

Comment: @Siva i don't really have a good idea how to user "Record Sort Expert", can you please provide me any useful link please ?

Comment: @Siva what actually i am trying to do is load only specific invoice data so that i can only print that one. hope you got my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I meant is:

Give your filtering in `Record Selection formula`, Now to sport record selection formula follow below path in `crystal report`:

```
Report ---> Selection Formula ----> Record
```

now a window is opened and enter your conditon there.

```
E.g: {Invoice Number}=1
```

Now run the report... you will get only data for `Invoice Number` 1

Use the [link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner/reportdesigner/crtskcustomizingrecordselectionformulas.htm) to understand the `Record Selection Formula`

Comment: 1 ) there is no way to enter my condition here
2 ) i am taking condition on run time from textbox value, like if its one in text box then it will show only 1 invoice with invoice no 1
please see the video link : http://screencast.com/t/E0hsWhno

Comment: Ok I saw the video... now that is not the way to go to record selection... go to tab `Report` which will be present in the line of `File, Edit.....Help` and from there go to `Record Sort Expert`. Second option will be in the option that you have tried why don't you try selecting any one field in the `Record selection window` may be that may lead you to the record selection window... There are will be 2 to 3 ways you can accomplish this task.. try and let me know.